# htaccess redirect url with space in it

Tags: .htaccess

Stupidly, I have sent out a newsletter without checking the links. One of which is broken so I want to handle this with htaccess.

My URL that is being linked to is:

http://www.domain.com.au/www.domain.com.au/campers-and-motorhomes/ne%20w-zealand/camper-rentals/

where the actual page is:
http://www.domain.com.au/campers-and-motorhomes/new-zealand/camper-rentals/

Note the space in new zealand as well as the additional www.domain.com.au

How can I set this up in htaccess?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't have to manipulate the URL, you can use a simple [Redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect):

```
Redirect /www.domain.com.au/campers-and-motorhomes/ne%20w-zealand/camper-rentals/  http://www.domain.com.au/campers-and-motorhomes/new-zealand/camper-rentals/
```

**Edit** If Apache doesn't like the space unquoted as `%20`, try quoting the whole thing with a real space in there:

```
Redirect "/www.domain.com.au/campers-and-motorhomes/ne w-zealand/camper-rentals/"  http://www.domain.com.au/campers-and-motorhomes/new-zealand/camper-rentals/
```

**Edit2** If it's appending a query string, you will need to use mod_rewrite to get rid of the querystring rather than a simple redirect, I'm afraid.

```
RewriteEngine On
# If the request starts with www.domain.com.au, it is the broken link
# Rewrite to the proper URL and put ? on the end to remove the query string
RewriteRule ^www\.domain\.com\.au http://www.domain.com.au/campers-and-motorhomes/new-zealand/camper-rentals/? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm a total novice at htaccess, does this need to go in the  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> block or can it just sit by itsself?

Comment: @Fraser Technically it's part of mod_alias so you can wrap it in side `<IfModule mod_alias.c>`, but that probably isn't necessary since mod_alias is just about always installed and enabled.

Comment: Thanks again. Unfortunately it's not picking up the page. It seems to be the space throwing it off (the redirect works with other URLs without a space). I've tried escaping it with \ but this gives me an internal server error. Any ideas?

Comment: I managed to get it to pick the page up by swapping %20 with a space and putting the URL in quotation marks however it is now redirecing with a huge querystring of the original url which is breaking the page. How can I remove the querystring?

Comment: You are my hero. Thank you Michael. Very much appreciated