# htaccess to replace space in url and redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, replace, space

I am newbie and want to solve a problem.
I read same question but misunderstand:

> [htaccess redirect url with space in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11444026/htaccess-redirect-url-with-space-in-it)

Please help me.
My site use wordpress with custom fields and tags.

Custom Fields make lot of link such as:

```
http://domain.com/tag/Miss Earth
http://domain.com/tag/Miss World
http://domain.com/tag/Miss England
...
```

(Space not %20)
Of cource I also create tags: Miss Earth, Miss World, Miss England... but above links are not exist (space (" ") must be replaced by "-" and "M" by "m" and "E" by "e"...

I need use htaccess to replace space (" ") character to "-" and auto redirect to really tags:

```
http://domain.com/tag/miss-earth
http://domain.com/tag/miss-world
http://domain.com/tag/miss-england
```

Please help me clearly, I am stupid with htaccess.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these rules to the htaccess file in your document root, preferably above any wordpress rules that are already in the file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?tag/(.*)\ (.*)$ /tag/$1-$2   [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Last I add on the bottom of htaccess file, it doesn't word, move under "RewriteEngine On" It works! Thanks Jon Lin

Comment: @VaiLeu Yeah, which is why I said to add them above your other rules. You should check the green check mark to mark the answer as accepted.